# SharePoint 2007: Calulated Column

Tags: sharepoint

I need to implement the following logic on a calculated column in a list...
Columns: Need Ticket, qty, and Price.
1.-If qty. is >= 20 AND Price >= 150 
2.- OR IF Price >= 750
Then set the text value to "need a ticket", if it is not met then set value to "Don't need a ticket"

I've tried several variations of this formula with no luck:

=IF(AND(qty>= 20, Price >= 750), "need a ticket", "Don't need a ticket")
 and:
=IF(OR(qty>= 20, Price >= 750), "need a ticket", "Don't need a ticket")

I am stuck and can't seem to be able to compose the formula for the two possible variations of the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relation to Nats answer above, there is no need to have AND(Price>= 750). Just write

```
=IF(OR(AND(Qty>=20,Price>=150),Price>=750),"don't need a ticket","need a ticket")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to nest then "AND" structure inside an "OR"
e.g.

```
=IF(OR(AND(Qty>=20,Price>=150),AND(Price>=750)),"don't need a ticket","need a ticket")
```